# Не читается файл переданный через socket

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, сокет

Я передаю файл-картинку програмкой на qt через интернет по сокетам:

```
    QFile file("/home/user/Изображения/hats.jpg");
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) { qDebug() <<"Error open file";}
        QByteArray arrfile = file.readAll();
        pClientSocket->write(arrfile);
        pClientSocket->flush();

Я принимаю файл програмкой на android:
  tc.in = client.getInputStream();
                    tc.isr = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                    tc.br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while (true) {
                try { 
                    int bufsize = 8192;
                    byte[] buf = new byte[bufsize];
                    int rlen = tc.in.read(buf);
                    if(tc.br.ready() && rlen>-1) {
                        File dst = new File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/ggg/hats.jpg");
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
                        out.write(buf, 0, rlen);
                        while ((rlen = tc.in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, rlen);
                            DebagClass.mLog("Avaiaiblerlen="+rlen);
                            DebagClass.mLog("Avaiaible="+tc.in.available());
                            DebagClass.mLog("space0");
                            File src = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/hats.jpg");
                            DebagClass.mLog("space src="+src.getTotalSpace());
                            DebagClass.mLog("space dest="+dst.getTotalSpace());
                        }
                        DebagClass.mLog("space20"); out.close();
                        File src = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/hats.jpg");
                        DebagClass.mLog("space2 src="+src.getTotalSpace());
                        DebagClass.mLog("space2 dest="+dst.getTotalSpace());

                    }
```

Все замечaтельно работает файлик передается, даже размеры файлов совпадают. Но вместо картинки открывается пустой экран. Еще почему то не выводится отладочное сообщение после цикла while, вроде должно выводится. Что я не делаю не так? 
ps Кстати BufferedReader мне нужен, только потому что там есть ready() так оно на нем зависает и не крутиться в бесконечном цикле, мне кажется что так меньше ресурсов ест, хотя может я не прав, х.з. А может из за этого, буду проверять. tc - просто обьект класса где хранятся переменные.

Comment: А вы не выводите на экран, а в файл принятые данные сохраняйте. И потом побайтно сравнивайте с исходными данными.

Comment: Короче проблема решена это мое бокопорство, я до этого еще 1 пакет посылал вот он и дописывал строку и картинка не читалась, не знаю писать правильный ответ или нет, код должен быть рабочим еще допроверяю.